# c++ Boost Multithread how to pass class object to argument

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I have class name BasicExcelCell. When I use it, this how to call

```
BasicExcelCell* c;
//Normal call
c->TTiTraceParserConv(TTiAsciiTraceOutputDL.GetBuffer(0));

//How to pass it the boost thread argument?
boost::thread t1(&YExcel::BasicExcelCell::TTiTraceParserConv,TTiAsciiTraceOutputDL.GetBuffer(0));

t1.join();
```

I had couple ways but I kept getting error when compile. Any advises, I appreciate. I had seen some basic examples from google.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the instance you want to call the member function on:

```
                                                             This
                                                              ↓
boost::thread t1(&YExcel::BasicExcelCell::TTiTraceParserConv, c, TTiAsciiTraceOutputDL.GetBuffer(0));
```

Comment: Passed the compiler. thanks. Is this a correct way to use multi-tread?

Comment: @user: well, it depends on what your goal is. This is a correct way of launching a thread, but there are much more things about multi-threading than just launching threads.

Comment: c->UeAndCellParamParseUL(TTiAsciiTraceOutputUL.GetBuffer(0),NumOfLines,GHOSTFILTER)  as you noticed, my function has more than one parameter. When pass it to thread arg, it complaint. How do I pass a function with more than paramter when using thread. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @user: to save our time you can just look at the documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor). You can ask if there is something specific you can't understand. Goodluck.